# How can I put regular text and animated text on the same line?

Tags: html

How can I put everything on the same line? See http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5AL/4/

It doesn't work with 2 `<p>` tags

Many thanks

HTML

```
<p>The number is <p id="dynamic-number">1</p> . Please confirm</p>
```

JS

```
var currentNumber = $('#dynamic-number').text();

$({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: 900}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() { 
        $('#dynamic-number').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue)); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/zQ5AL/5/

here's an update to your fiddle..

solution:

```
<p>The number is <span id="dynamic-number">1</span> . Please confirm</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a p tag inside a p tag. Try:

```
<p>The number is <span id="dynamic-number">1</span> . Please confirm</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a span element

```
<p>The number is <span id="dynamic-number">1</span> . Please confirm</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

I have added few css:

```
#dynamic-number {
   color: #000;
    font: bold 35px Arial;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    text-align: center; 
}
p {  margin:0;padding:0;float:left;}
```

Remove the `margin,padding` and set the `float:left`

[Here is the Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/zQ5AL/6/)